# How do I toggle an activity with a single button?

Tags: delphi

I have a problem with a start and stop button.

[image: see here]

When I click start, it can't stop exact we exit: How can I can make it like this:

Before

[image]

After

[image]

My code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  TServiceThread.Create;
end;
```

My friend gave this code, but it don't work — when I click start, it closes.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  TServiceThread.Create;
  if (button1.Caption='&Start') then
  begin
    Button1.Enabled := True;
    button1.Caption:='&Stop';
  end
  else
  begin
    Button1.Enabled := True;
    close;
    button1.Caption:='&Start';
  end;
end;
```

What is the solution?

Comment: The form is closing because you have a close statement just before button1.Caption:='&Start'; What are you trying to stop and start? Is it the service thread?

Comment: i don't know about that, my friend give that code i think code he give to me still have bug , sorry i just 2week study with delphi , i'm so sorry if make you confused but i'm very confused too -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a `Close` in your second `Button1Click` event, which will close the form. Remove it and you've solved that problem.

Thinking that you're probably wanting to start and stop the thread, you need to do a few things.

First, you need to keep a reference to the thread, so add a new variable to your form definition:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    FServiceThread: TServiceThread;
  ...
  end;
```

Now, in your `Button1Click` handler:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  try
    if FServiceThread = nil then
      FServiceThread := TServiceThread.Create;

    if (Button1.Caption = '&Start') then
    begin
      Button1.Caption := '&Stop';
      FServiceThread.Start;
    end
    else
    begin
      Button1.Caption := '&Start';
      FServiceThread.Terminate;
    end;
  finally
    Button1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;
```

Note that you need to either set the thread's `FreeOnTerminate` property to `True` (which will automatically free the thread when it's terminated), or manually free the thread yourself in the form's `OnClose` or `OnDestroy` events. If you use `FreeOnTerminate`, then you should add an event for the thread's `OnTerminate` event and use it to set `FServiceThread := nil;` to allow a new one to be created the next time the `Start` button is clicked.

Comment: `FServiceThread.Stop` -> `FServiceThread.Start` and it may be worth talking about `FreeOnTerminate` given that the code in the Q does not attempt to free the thread.

Comment: `FServiceThread := TServiceThread.Create(True);  // Create suspended` give me `[Error] Unit1.pas(37): Too many actual parameters` , and `FServiceThread.Stop;` give `[Error] Unit1.pas(42): Undeclared identifier: 'Stop'` what must i do ? thanks for answer

Comment: now i just have one problem `FServiceThread := TServiceThread.Create(True); // Create suspended` give error message `[Error] Unit1.pas(37): Too many actual parameters` ,any solution please ?

Comment: @rihsano Ken has assumed that `TServiceThread` has the same constructor as `TThread`. Clearly that's not the case. You'll need to call the constructor for your class as appropriate. Since we cannot see your class, we are guessing. Ken's example assumes that the thread is created suspended and then started later.

Comment: `FServiceThread := TServiceThread.Create(True);` i delete the (True) and error are gone , if it's not there any side effects? and now my problem is fix thanks Ken White and David Heffernan !!! Very big thanks